# How would you create a group identifier based on one column, but sorted by another?

Tags: t-sql

I am attempting to create column `Group` via T-SQL.

If a cluster of accounts are in a row, consider that as one group. if the account is seen again lower in the list (cluster or not), then consider it a new group. This seems straight forward, but I cannot seem to see the solution... Below there are three clusters of account 3456, each having a different group number (Group 1,4, and 6)

```
+-------+---------+------+
| Group | Account | Sort |
+-------+---------+------+
|     1 |    3456 |    1 |
|     1 |    3456 |    2 |
|     2 |    9878 |    3 |
|     3 |    5679 |    4 |
|     4 |    3456 |    5 |
|     4 |    3456 |    6 |
|     4 |    3456 |    7 |
|     5 |    1295 |    8 |
|     6 |    3456 |    9 |
+-------+---------+------+
```

UPDATE: I left this out of the original requirements, but a cluster of accounts could have more than two accounts. I updated the example data to include this scenario.

Comment: What you did so far?

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: requirement is not clear. please post raw data/table

Comment: The `Group` column does not exist.  He wants to generate this based on the other 2 columns.

Comment: Thanks for the reformat Eric! I have attempted using a solution using RANK(), DENSE_RANK(), Even a solution using LEAD() to try to indicate a break in pattern, and I got lost in the weeds trying to juggle the data into temp tables... This seems like a simple task, but it eludes me for sure... jtate is correct, expected output is the Group column. Raw data/table is account and Sort columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
--Sample Data
DECLARE @table TABLE (Account INT, Sort INT);
INSERT @table
VALUES (3456,1),(3456,2),(9878,3),(5679,4),(3456,5),(3456,6),(1295,7),(3456,8);

--Solution
SELECT [Group] = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY grouper.groupID), grouper.Account, grouper.Sort
FROM
(
  SELECT t.*, groupID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.sort) + 
              CASE t.Account WHEN LEAD(t.Account,1) OVER (ORDER BY t.sort) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  FROM @table AS t
) AS grouper;
```

**Results:**

```
Group   Account     Sort
------- ----------- -----------
1       3456        1
1       3456        2
2       9878        3
3       5679        4
4       3456        5
4       3456        6
5       1295        7
6       3456        8
```

**Update based on OPs comment below (20190508)**

I spent a couple days banging my head on how to handle groups of three or more; it was surprisingly difficult but what I came up with handles bigger clusters and is **way better than my first answer**. I updated the sample data to include bigger clusters.

Note that I include a UNIQUE constraint for the sort column - this creates a unique index. You don't need the constraint for this solution to work but, having an index on that column (clustered, nonclustered unique or just nonclustered) will improve the performance dramatically.

```
--Sample Data
DECLARE @table TABLE (Account INT, Sort INT UNIQUE);
INSERT @table
VALUES (3456,1),(3456,2),(9878,3),(5679,4),(3456,5),(3456,6),(1295,7),(1295,8),(1295,9),(1295,10),(3456,11);

-- Better solution
WITH Groups AS
(
  SELECT t.*, Grouper =
    CASE t.Account WHEN LAG(t.Account,1,t.Account) OVER (ORDER BY t.Sort) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  FROM @table AS t
)
SELECT [Group] = SUM(sg.Grouper) OVER (ORDER BY sg.Sort)+1, sg.Account, sg.Sort
FROM   Groups AS sg;
```

Results:

```
Group       Account     Sort
----------- ----------- -----------
1           3456        1
1           3456        2
2           9878        3
3           5679        4
4           3456        5
4           3456        6
5           1295        7
5           1295        8
5           1295        9
5           1295        10
6           3456        11
```

Comment: Man! I was so close... Adding in the Row_Number() was what I was missing. Thank you very much for connecting the dots... This is spot on.

Comment: So, I left out a requirement that there could be more than two accounts in a cluster. How would this change your solution as the current logic would not stand up.

Comment: Great work! Your update is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you Alan!